# Loading Content in CodeMirror with XHR

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Has there been any work yet to load the Content in CodeMirror with XHR

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What exactly do you want to do? You can set the code via `setCode` and it does not matter where it comes from.

Comment: Hmm I see. I'll take a look a setCode in the Docs

Answer (score -1):

I did this in that way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlToFile,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#contentForEditor").html("<textarea id='editor'></textarea>");
        $('#editor').html(data);
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(
            document.getElementById('editor')
        )
    }
})
```

This is quite simply. Load by ajax file from the server. Next in `success` callback create `textarea` tag and attach this tag to some exiting element. Next put file loaded from server to `textarea`. Last step is run `CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...)` on created `textarea`